# (C++) Why can't I rely on an extration operator to act as an iterator?

Tags: c++, string, integer, extract, fstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("input.txt");
    char currentChar;
    int charCount = 0;

    while (file >> currentChar)
    {
        charCount++;
        if (currentChar == 'a')
        {
            std::cout << charCount;
        }
    }
```

in the above, the charCount that's printed is massively large. If I move charcount into the if statement and turn the input into repetitions of the character 'a', it counts correctly (or would count the number of a's correctly). Is "file >> currentChar" what's causing the charCount number to increment so highly? And if so, what's it doing? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not "massively large".  You're simply outputting the current count every time you encounter the letter `a`, and because you don't include any whitespace or newlines, then every number will be joined together and appear like a huge number.

Try this:

```
std::cout << charCount << std::endl;
```

And consider doing this just once *after* the loop.  Unless for some reason you want to show all intermediate counts.

Comment: Actually you're right - in my code that I rewrote here in stackoverflow, I initialized the charCount to zero. In my actual code, it's not initialized. I was incrementing an uninitialized variable which is why I was getting values north of 1 million, even though the input file was only a few hundred chars long and there was only one 'a' in it. I was hoping to print out its position in the file. I appreciate the clarification that the number shouldn't be that high though!

Comment: I suspected that may have also been the case, but I have to give the benefit of the doubt when code is written in a question.  It is very important that you don't retype your program when asking questions.  You must copy/paste.  You could have further helped your question by showing the actual output and indicating how many `a` characters were in the file.  This would have helped identify the issue, which would have then made it obvious that your question's code does not match reality.